# Connect a script to an image

Tags: javascript, tabs, window

In the code written below, an URL opens in a resizable window. But I only want it to open when people click on an image. How do I connect this to an image? So when people click on the image, the code belows starts working.

```
<script>
window.open("http://www.example-url.com","mywin","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=3‌​00,height=195");
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried/searched anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, `<img onClick="openWindow()" src="PATH/TO/IMG"/>`

And in the javascript:

```
function openWindow() {
window.open("http://www.example-url.com","mywin","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=3‌​00,height=195");
}
```

Comment: Thanks the code is working! I still have one question left..
What if I want to use this function for like 10 different images?
For example:
Image1 opens URL1
Image 2 opens URL2
Etc. 
Now all the different images are opening the same link/URL

Comment: As far as I know you need to link them to different images, but there might be a better way to do it. Im pretty new to JS

Comment: But if the code is working could you please checkmark my answer